# how to use rest and soap api in Drupal 7

Tags: api, drupal, drupal-7

I could not find any document about using rest or soap api in drupal 7

it would be great if some one gives me a path or document reference about this

Thanks.

Comment: Checkout the [services](https://www.drupal.org/project/services) module, you can do whatever you want. Here is the [documentation](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/services).

Comment: Thanks for your info, I will checkit and let you know.

Comment: We want API's to Drupal 7 version

Comment: Well, after clicking the link, you'll need to take an additional second of your time to *read* the information that prints on the screen, by doing that you will probably be able to understand the meaning of this information and react accordingly, as you seem to do quite well here on SO. If you can't manage to do that by yourself or if you don't want to spend too much time reading, hopefully you still have the selected quotes provided by the answer below, but again, it will take some time to interpret all these characters. I'm so sorry for that. I wish I could do more to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Drupal 7 does not have build-in REST API support. so you need to install [services](https://www.drupal.org/project/services) module.

> A standardized solution for building API's so that external clients
>   can communicate with Drupal. Out of the box it aims to support
>   anything Drupal Core supports and provides a code level API for other
>   modules to expose their features and functionality via HTTP. It
>   provide Drupal plugins that allow others to create their own
>   authentication mechanisms, request formats, and response formats.

for more information take a look at https://www.drupal.org/node/750036

> Services provides access to core functionality to remote clients
>   (things like nodes, users, taxonomy, etc.) The following projects
>   integrate with Services to provide the same functionality outside of
>   what is included in core

Additional help link: 
[How to create custom rest resources in drupal](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/restful-web-services-api/custom-rest-resources)